# SLES 12.2 VNC can not access desktop

Tags: vnc, vnc-viewer, sles

I am a total newbie in SLES and VNC. I installed fresh 12.2, then started a vncserver vncserver -geometry 1920x1080 :2.
But the vnc does not have access to the desktop. All folders and files are missing on the desktop.
And when I right click at the desktop, I have only limited option compare to direct access. Like I can not open terminal.
[image]

Does anyone know how to gain desktop access? Thank you very much.

I am using UltraVNC Viewer.

Answer (score -1):

A YaST2 module exist to enable remote access via the VNC module. Configure it, adjust the firewall to allow access to the VNC ports, if needed.